# MS Teams on Safari

Tags: safari, ms-teams

Every time I try to log into MS Teams from safari, it throws an error saying that "Teams is in preview for safari" and tells me to use the desktop application. It recommends disabling cross-site tracking in order to access Teams in safari, but I don't want to disable that option for obvious reasons. Is it the same for everyone or is there a fix for this?[image]

Comment: Download the app, I have it on two machines with the same work login credentials and no issues. Had issues via any browser and I have 3 (Safari, Firefox and Chrome, for various reasons)

Comment: That should be an answer @SolarMike and not a comment. There are some upsides and also some downsides to having the whole app. Using teams in browser can work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this "error" has been appearing since I started using Teams on macOS/Safari which was probably some time between BigSur or Catalina.

Browsers are different and therefore complex websites (like Teams) need to be optimized for the browsers. The fact is that Chrome is by far the most used Browser, therefore websites are well optimized for Chrome while Safari is far less popular and therefore less important to developers.

I would either just download the App or use another Browser like Chrome, Firefox...

Answer (score 1):

We are recommending the Edge browser for Mac users wanting to use teams / O365 web apps at work. It’s much easier since staff use that browser as their “office” and keep all the other browsers configured for existing bookmarks, saved passwords, settings they prefer.

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

We turn off just about every feature offered during the “onboarding” and it’s functionally a fast, de-cluttered chrome experience.